# Integration testing ActionMailer and ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, actionmailer, rspec3, rails-activejob

In the past, Rails 3, I've integrated action mailer testing with my Cucumber/Rspec-Capybara tests like the following example. With Rails 4, using the following doesn't seem to work.

I am able to see that the job is queued using enqueued_jobs.size. How do I initiate the enqueued job to ensure that the email subject, recipient and body are correctly being generated?

## app/controllers/robots_controller.rb

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if robot.create robot_params
      RobotMailer.hello_world(robot.id).deliver_later
      redirect_to robots_path, notice: 'New robot created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

## spec/features/robot_spec.rb

```
feature 'Robots' do
  scenario 'create a new robot' do
    login user
    visit '/robots'
    click_link 'Add Robot'
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Robbie'
    click_button 'Submit'

    expect(page).to have_content 'New robot created'

    new_robot_mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    expect(new_robot_mail.to) eq 'myemail@robots.com'
    expect(new_robot_mail.subject) eq "You've created a new robot named Robbie"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the rspec-activejob gem and the following code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(RSpec::ActiveJob)

  # clean out the queue after each spec
  config.after(:each) do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.enqueued_jobs = []
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.performed_jobs = []
  end

  config.around :each, perform_enqueued: true do |example|
    @old_perform_enqueued_jobs = ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
    example.run
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_jobs
  end

  config.around :each, perform_enqueued_at: true do |example|
    @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs =    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = true
    example.run
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_at_jobs = @old_perform_enqueued_at_jobs
  end
end
```

This lets me tag features/scenarios with `perform_enqueued: true` if I want the jobs to actually execute.

Comment: Thanks for this! Looks like code from the ActiveJob::TestHelper module. I just wasn't able to get it working. FWIW, you don't need to use the rspec-activejob gem as it only provides matchers. The around :each config is enough to trigger the jobs.